# Broken handler fix by clear cache temporarily

Tags: drupal-7, memcached

Im using drupal 7 + memcache. Everything was fine but some days ago im getting Broken handler in the views, I tried flush cache it resolve the issue but after some time again broken handler error appear.

Can anyone help me out. Is it an issue with memcache or something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue. Sometimes multiple views are broken and content is missing from pages. Clearing caches "fixes" all issues. One difference is that I've been using Boost rather than Memcache. I just tried disabling Boost to see whether that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Views 3.8, you can try to downgrade to 3.7 or add code in cache.inc in _views_fetch_data_build():

```
// Save data in seperate cache entries.
foreach ($cache as $key => $data) {
    $cid = 'views_data:' . $key;
    views_cache_set($cid, $data, TRUE);
}
```

source: comment #39 https://www.drupal.org/node/2153517